# In Ruby, can I pass each element of an array individually to a method that accepts *args?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a method that returns an array and another accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, is there a way to call the second method with each element of the array as an argument?

For example:

```
def arr
  ["a", "b", "c"]   
end

def bar(*args)
  args.each {|a| puts a}
end
```

I want to call

```
bar "a", "b" , "c"
```

Of course this is a simplified example, in reality arr could return an array of any size (say if it's an ActiveRecord find, and I want to pass all the results to bar), hence my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bar(*my_array)
```

This will flatten out the array into it's individual elements and pass them to the method as separate arguments.  You could do this to any kind of method, not only ones that accept *args.

So in your case:

```
bar *arr
```

Comment: Works great, and it's good to know that it has broader application -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` also when you give an array as an argument:

```
bar(*arr)
```